# Throwing thread in a unit in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm making a unit in which I throw a thread with BeginThread with a variable that is defined in the class.

Code:

```
unit practica;

interface

uses Windows;

type
  TTest = class
  private
  public
    probando: integer;
    procedure iniciar_thread;
    procedure load_now;
  end;

implementation

procedure TTest.load_now;
begin
  Sleep(probando);
end;

procedure TTest.iniciar_thread;
begin
  BeginThread(nil, 0, @TTest.load_now, nil, 0, PDWORD(0)^);
end;

end.
```

Form :

```
procedure TForm1.testClick(Sender: TObject);
  test:TTest;
begin
  test := TTest.Create();
  test.probando := 1000;
  test.iniciar_thread;
end;
```

When compiling get no error, but when you run the function I get this:

```
Exception EAccessViolation in module test.exe
    System Error. Code5
    Runtime error 217
```

As I solve this?

Comment: You mean "Throw"  as in "launch"?  I'm only asking because "throw" is usually used in the sense of "throwing an exception" ...

Comment: Launch a function thread using BeginThread in the unit

Comment: If you mean *starting a thread*, write *starting a thread*. It makes it much easier to understand your question if you say what you mean. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a **non-static class method** as the thread procedure for `BeginThread()`.  Look at the declaration of `BeginThread()`:

```
type
  TThreadFunc = function(Parameter: Pointer): Integer;

function BeginThread(SecurityAttributes: Pointer; StackSize: LongWord;
  ThreadFunc: TThreadFunc; Parameter: Pointer; CreationFlags: LongWord;
  var ThreadId: TThreadID): Integer;
```

As you can see, it is expecting a stand-alone function, not a class method.  Even if it did, your class method doesn't even have the correct signature anyway.

Try something more like this instead:

```
unit practica;

interface

type
  TTest = class
  private
    FThread: Integer;
  public
    probando: integer;
    procedure iniciar_thread;
    procedure load_now;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Windows;

procedure TTest.load_now;
begin
  Sleep(probando);
end;

function MyThreadFunc(Parameter: Pointer): Integer;
begin
  TTest(Parameter).load_now;
end;

procedure TTest.iniciar_thread;
var
  ThreadId: TThreadID;
begin
  FThread := BeginThread(nil, 0, MyThreadFunc, Self, 0, ThreadId);
end;

end.
```

And don't forget to terminate your thread, `CloseHandle()` the thread handle returned by `BeginThread()`, and `Free()` your `TTest` object when you are done using everything.

Typically, you shouldn't use `BeginThread()` directly. You should derive a class from `TThread` instead:

```
unit practica;

interface

type
  TTest = class
  public
    probando: integer;
    procedure iniciar_thread;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Classes, Windows;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FTest: TTest;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ATest: TTest);
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(ATest: TTest);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FTest := ATest;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  Sleep(FTest.probando);
end;

procedure TTest.iniciar_thread;
begin
  TMyThread.Create(Self);
end;

end.
```

Comment: The access violation could also be coming from passing `PDWORD(0)^` as the `var` parameter to the threadId.  The method needs a valid address to write the thread id value to.  That's not to say that everything else you say isn't correct about what is wrong, of course.  With no `self` parameter the attempt to access the instance variable `probando` would also result in an AV.

Comment: @J...: On Windows, `BeginThread()` is a wrapper for the Win32 `CreateThread()` function, which allows that particular parameter to be NULL if the caller does not want the thread ID.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I always use the ThreadID parameter when calling `BeginThread` so this seemed odd to me, but MSDN agrees it can be NULL.

Comment: Oh my you show know how mich I've passed `PLongInt(nil)^` to var arguments in Delphi's Windows API calls...

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Is it kosher to call `CloseHandle()` on the handle returned by `BeginThread` immediately after calling the latter (to avoid the baggage of keeping track of handles)? I've ran across this in a lot of old code I've had to maintain (mostly Delphi 2007). I've never actually seen it stated authoritatively that it was okay. Most say "Call `CloseHandle() after the thread is finished" or similar. But in this case, it's a thread that is "fire and forget" for operations that take longer, with the thread (or threads) sending a windows message back to the main application when finished.

Comment: @jep yes, it is OK to close the thread handle immediately. The thread will continue running until the thread procedure exits. Though, you should consider keeping it open until you get that message, in case the app needs to exit before the thread is finished, you have something to wait on to make sure any resources the thread uses remain valid until the thread exits before the app exits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Understood, but in this case all the resources are internal to the applications heap, so there's not a lot of worry about them not being released when the application quits (even if it's a bit gauche).